# Do all ActiveMQ clients need a client certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, jms, activemq-classic

I have ActiveMQ (JMS) and want to connect multiple clients.

To support SSL security in Java clients, Apache ActiveMQ provides ssl support.
[ActiveMQ how-do-i-use-ssl](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html). If you want to verify client certificates, you need to take extra work for every client.

*Is a client certificate necessary?*

Customers can install the clients themselves, so it is not possible for me to create a certificate for every client.
Is my client connection then secure?